# What is the better between search text and number in mysql?

Tags: mysql

What is the better between search text and number in mysql ?

EG:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE country = 'Australia' ";
```

and

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE country = '10899' ";
```

for load faster from database.

Comment: The 2nd query is searching text as well.

Comment: That query is searching text in both cases. In any case, for a simple query like that you won't notice the difference.

Comment: As with anything performance-related: ***you must measure.***

Comment: -- Matt Ball -  what it's mean `you must measure.` ?

Answer (score 1):

For Faster Searching you need to perform search operation via primary key which searches data faster because primary key is unique key. Example you provided are both performing text search...

Answer (score 0):

Both of your queries are searching by text, as you use single quotes to surround the value. To search by number, you don't have to surround the value by quotes.

To answer your question about performance, you should search by primary key or indexed columns for better speed if you have huge amount of data. In small dataset, you won't notice a difference, as simple SELECT usually finished in split seconds.

Comment: EG: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 12 ";` is better speed more than in my question ?

Comment: Yes, if you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Here you asked whats better Number or Text ? But there are so many factors thats need to take into consideration to improve `where` clause performance.

Biggest fear regarding `where` clause is full table scan and to avoid so you have to use `index`.
"If the optimizer gets confused or cannot find an appropriate index that matches the WHERE clause, the optimizer will read every row in the table."

Whenever you create any clusted index (Primary Key) on table, Clustered indexes sort and store the data rows in the table or view based on their key values.
Now here you can think about `Text` or `Number` 
So you can go with number as sorting time required is less compared to text.

Things to improve `where` clause:

1) Use of Primary Key column in where clause (automatically uniqueness and NOT NULL comes)

2) If not possible with primary key column atleast have index on the column used in where cluse (Prefer `Number` as sorting is faster w.r.t large amount of data)